# How to see full signature for `__init__`, when pydoc3 shows `See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydoc

I find `pydoc3` very helpful for getting help on classes and functions.

However, it often shows the help for `__init__` as: `See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.` (see below)

Using the `python3` REPL, I don't know to get the full signature for `__init__`. How do I get the full signature for `__init__`, and why can't `pydoc3` display it?

`pydoc3 queue.Queue`:

```
Help on class Queue in queue:

queue.Queue = class Queue(builtins.object)
 |  queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
 |
 |  Create a queue object with a given maximum size.
 |
 |  If maxsize is <= 0, the queue size is infinite.
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __init__(self, maxsize=0)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking about. `__init__(self, maxsize=0)` is the full signature of the method. There's no docstring for `__init__` because it would be redundant with the docstring for the whole class, which is what you see above (starting with `queue.Queue(maxsize=0)` and ending just before the `Methods defined here:` line).

Comment: But why does it say “accurate signature”?

Comment: Some builtin types don't have accurate signatures on their `__init__` or `__new__` methods (check `range` for an example). But the class docstring will properly describe their API, which is why pydoc suggests you look there, when there's no method-specific docstring.